# Connect external sensor to CANoe

Tags: canoe

I am totally new to stackoverflow. I have a question Related to CANoe(Vector)

Is it possible to inject external sensor signals to ECU through CANoe,External sensor signals comes from an virtual simulation software Carmaker.

Comment: Hello Saravanan and welcome! 
Is the external sensor signal simulation in blf format? 

Also, you can keep the title without introduction, and put something shorter and compact, straight to the point, so people will read it. 
Like : CANoe simulation of external sensors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can connect CarMaker to CANoe by using FMI.

There is a video on [YouTube](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiHv-Gv5prgAhUSGewKHZ16DmoQwqsBMAB6BAgFEAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DSzjAOvUkcnI&usg=AOvVaw1_h23S2lqA2fWgMX4ykL2f) roughly showing how to connect.

You can set it up so that signals from CANoe show up in Carmaker and vice versa.

FMI should be documented pretty well in CANoe's help. Just get back here if you need further help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a customer account at IPG Carmaker, there is also an example for the FMI connection to CANoe you can download from 'Tips and Tricks' section of the website after logging in. Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Pooja, welcome to StackOverflow! Can you include the example here? It seems unlikely that your answer as it currently stands solves the OP's question by itself.

Comment: Hey @Brydenr, the reason I cannot (should not) do that is because it is only accessible to people with valid CarMaker licenses and logged in with their accounts. It would be illegal to share the docs in any form outside of these accounts. Just wanted to point OP in the right direction :)